# Can not read value after angular push

Tags: javascript, angularjs, return, push

I have some code like below:

```
$scope.offer = [];
angular.forEach($scope.details, function (product) {
  SomeAPI.ById.query({ product: product.id }, function (response) {
    $scope.offer.push(response);
  });
  return $scope.offer;
});
console.log($scope.offer);
```

Why do the console log still out put "**`[]`**"?
On the page, `{{ offer }}` display value correctly.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

your API is async function

```
SomeAPI.ById.query({ product: product.id }, callback);  
console.log('query is still running. callback will be done later')
```

the callback above will be invoked later after asynchronous function completed. your console.log get called immediately